# Override Taxonomy Pages without entire page override

Tags: 7, theming

I need to override Taxonomy page (page--taxonomy--term.tpl.php) and wondering if it's possible to just override the content section of the page instead of the whole page.

I don't want to print all other regions again as I will to update different page tpls if I update some other part of the page template.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module to create custom layout.

Or :

2. You can override `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` in your theme directory as following :

   `taxonomy-term--[vocabulary-machine-name|tid].tpl.php`

I would suggest panel rather than overriding template files.

Comment: Thanks .. taxonomy-term--[vocabulary-machine-name].tpl.php is what I need but doing an override kills other regions too.

Comment: Regions are defined in `page.tpl.php`. I don't think that copy the `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` from taxonomy module into your theme would affect the regions. Well, you can use panel module too which is easy to use.